# access services over internet not working(anymore)

Tags: raspbmc

Cant access over internet?

I recently managed to get the pi working so i could access services over the internet.

i.e `<external-ip>:8088` was working fine yesterday.

I had trouble getting this working initially, and tried a combination of things.
but eventually did have this working.

today its not working, only thing i can think that may have changed was by doing a reboot?

i can still access the services over the lan i.e `192.168.2.7:8088`

i think i can assume the router/port forwarding is working ok - so is it something with the raspberry pi?

Comment: If you can access it on the 192.168.2.7:8088 port/address and there is no other IP address on that RPi, you most likely have a port forwarding issue. MAybe your RPi IP address changed on reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Quite probably the problem is that your external IP has changed since yesterday. Can you check that this is not the case?
In this case, the easiest way to get things up to date is to configure a Dynamic DNS client on your RPi so at every boot it will update the IP assigned to a hostname of your choice, then you'll be capable to reach your Pi from the outside by using this hostname, regardless of the real IP. 
Search for "**DDNS Raspberry pi**" and you will find a lot of ways and public,free services that provide DDNS.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have that problem, it means that your IP changed. To solve it, just check it by either going to http://www.whatismyip.com/ or like me, make this batch file:

Execute,

```
sudo nano myip.sh
```

and insert this code,

```
#!/bin/bash
# Name: myip
# Author: O-P
# Purpose: Check current public IP address

curl -s checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

Ctrl + X and save it.

Now just run it using ./myip.sh

You can also get a dynamic DNS, there is several ways to do this, I'll give you an example of a free one.

Register in http://freedns.afraid.org/signup/ and login.

Go to **Subdomains** and create a free one.

Next go to **Dynamic DNS**, you should have the subdomain you created there. Right click **Direct URL**, and copy the key that appears in the url. Like,

> [http://some.subdomain.com/dynamic/update.php?[key]](http://some.subdomain.com/dynamic/update.php?%5bkey%5d)

Next install inadyn, this is a DNS updater, what it will do is to make sure it maintains the DNS you choose, just type,

```
sudo apt-get install inadyn
```

and configure it,

```
sudo nano /etc/inadyn.conf
```

with the following,

```
--username [yourusername]
--password [yourpassword]
--update_period 3600
--forced_update_period 14400
--alias [yourdomain],[key]
--background
--dyndns_system default@freedns.afraid.org
--syslog
```

Now, we need to ensure that the Inadyn runs automatically after every reboot, run this on the console,

```
export EDITOR=gedit && sudo crontab -e
```

And add the following line,

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/inadyn
```

Next just reboot the system,

```
sudo reboot
```

After it has done rebooting just check if it is working,

```
ps -A | grep inadyn
```

And you are good to go. You can connect to it using the domain you choose.

Have fun.